# Select Distinct From Table - Two Columns No Column Should Have Repetition

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I a select against a table A for example which contains these records.

```
|Column1|Column2|
| A      |F     |
| A      | G    |
| B      |G     |
| B      |H     |
| C      |H     |
| D      |H     |
| E      |I     |
```

My expected result is:

```
|Column1 |Column2|
| A      | F     |
| B      | G     |
| C      | H     |
| E      | I     |
```

All columns should have a unique value in them.

What query statement can I use for this?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to display all column1 values and all column2 values and then you want to filter them such that you still show all the values, but none are duplicates? That is a very strange request. To guarantee that you would have to write a procedure looping through all combinations till it succeeds or ends without success.

Comment: is there a way that only a query? I plan to do it in Java if all else fails. But as much as possible, I want to be able to handle it via query only.

Comment: As I have already said, your request looks strange and you might want to think it over. It would be easy to give a list of all values A, B, C, D, ..., but to use the combinations given and to try to remove this or that row till the end result contains all values but no duplicates, can only done by try & error - maybe with the help of some fuzzy logic. This is nothing SQL can do for you.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select 
    MIN(Column1) Column1, 
    Column2 
from(
    select 
        Column1, 
        MIN(Column2) Column2 
    from YourTable
    group by Column1 
)x group by Column2
order by 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f922e/2)

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work for this scenario.

```
create table YourTable (Column1 varchar2(10), 
                        Column2 varchar2(10));

insert into YourTable values ('B','F');
insert into YourTable values ('B','G');
insert into YourTable values ('B','H');
insert into YourTable values ('C','F');
insert into YourTable values ('C','G');
insert into YourTable values ('C','H');
insert into YourTable values ('D','F');
insert into YourTable values ('D','G');
insert into YourTable values ('D','H');
```

My expectation is

B F
C G
D H

but I only got

B F

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please delete this post. This section is only for answering the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. Also, you can edit your question and change the sample data with the one posted here.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.val, b.val FROM
(
 SELECT val, rownum as rno 
  FROM
  (
   SELECT distinct column1 as val
     FROM YourTable 
  )) a,
  (
   SELECT val, rownum as rno 
     FROM
  (
    SELECT distinct column2 as val
      FROM YourTable 
  )) b
  WHERE a.rno = b.rno
  ORDER BY 1
  /

VAL VAL_1
-----------
 B  F
 C  G
 D  H
```

OR

```
select column1 as val from YourTable 
UNION
select column2 from YourTable 

VAL
-----
B
C
D
F
G
H
```